# How overlapping directive(one of directives angular-bootstrap) in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I using lib angular-bootstrap, and I had overlap one directive:

```
.directive('datepickerPopup', ['$compile', '$parse', '$document', '$position', 'dateFilter', 'dateParser', 'datepickerPopupConfig',
function ($compile, $parse, $document, $position, dateFilter, dateParser, datepickerPopupConfig) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      isOpen: '=?',
      currentText: '@',
      clearText: '@',
      closeText: '@',
      dateDisabled: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      /* Other code in lib */  
      scope.$watch('isOpen', function(value) {
        if (value) {
          console.log("watch lib dir");
          scope.$broadcast('datepicker.focus');
          scope.position = appendToBody ? $position.offset(element) : $position.position(element);
          scope.position.top = scope.position.top + element.prop('offsetHeight') + 50;
          $document.bind('click', documentClickBind);
        } else {
          $document.unbind('click', documentClickBind);
        }
      });
      /* Other code in lib */    
    }
  };
}])
```

I create custom directive, and not using require directive(because in html layout I using this directive as an attribute and beside another attribute I can't, because it will not fall into the scope of the first attribute), but simply written with the same signature:

```
.directive('datepickerPopup', ['$compile', '$parse', '$document', '$position', 'dateFilter', 'dateParser', 'datepickerPopupConfig',
    function ($compile, $parse, $document, $position, dateFilter, dateParser, datepickerPopupConfig) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            priority: 1,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                scope.$watch('isOpened', function(value) {
                    if(value){
                /*custom code */
                    }           
            });
            }
        };
    }])
```

But scope.$watch not sees 'isOpened' (therefore not working corrected), and I added in definition custom directive:

```
scope: {
          isOpen: '=?'
}
```

And after in console catch throw exception:

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [datepickerPopup, datepickerPopup] asking for new/isolated scope on: <input type="text" name="callDate" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="callDate" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" datepicker-positioning="" is-open="opened" ng-required="true">
```

How overlaping lib directive not using require?

Comment: why don't you give the directive a different name?

Comment: Because it will not override lib directive if I will give different name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because you can't redefine directives in Angular. You need to use decorator to extend/replace them.

```
app.config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('datepickerPopupDirective', ['$delegate', '$compile', '$parse', '$document', '$position', 'dateFilter', 'dateParser', 'datepickerPopupConfig', function($delegate, $compile, $parse, $document, $position, dateFilter, dateParser, datepickerPopupConfig) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            priority: 1,
            scope: {
                isOpen: '=?'
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch('isOpen', function(value) {
                    if(value){
                /*custom code */
                    }           
            });
            }
        };
    }]);
});
```

If you don't plan to extend the original directive, you can omit `$delegate` dependency.

Comment: But this solution not correct, because if two datepicker, then both opened. How this problem solved?

Comment: Sure, it was an example of decorator. I've updated the code with isolated scope.